# which tool can draw the diagram like this

Tags: diagram

The following diagram like this image, the draw style is special, the line is free
[image]

Comment: Are you asking for a "tool" in the sense of a programming library or in the sense of an application? In the case of the latter (which I believe is the case), StackOverflow is not the right place for this question.